# Add table to list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I created a figure and for layout purposes I had to put it inside a table. Of course now it shows in the list of tables and not in the list of figures. Any idea how to make the table pass as a figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) (always a good idea) and use `\captionof{figure}{<figure caption>}` inside the `table` float:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
  \rule{.5\linewidth}{100pt}
  \caption{A table}

  \bigskip

  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) provides similar functionality.